# making a UIImageView go full screen when pressed

Tags: uiimageview

im new to this so please excuse anything ive missed

right so ive been working on an app for a few weeks now, i have done most of my app and now on the last tab (out of 5 tabs) the last tab is a photo gallery

it has 12 UIImageViews which i have a smaller version of an image in, and what i want to do is when each one is pressed, i want the image to go full screen with a new image that is the proper one ((the full size one) if that makes sense)

i have no code written so far as im completely stuck here.

any tips or references would be a great help

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

show those 12 images as a background image of different 12 buttons. then u can fire an event each time you click those button . 
  make sure you use a same image for UIControlStateHighlighted and UIControlStateNormal.